# Fortran communicating with another program using files

Tags: fortran, ipc

I have a program (lets call it a.exe) that reads some data from files, calculates something and then writes the result to another file.
I need to call a.exe from my own fortran code.

I came up with the following solution:

- write data in fortran to disk.
- call a.exe from fortran.
- a.exe reads now it's input file, does a calculation and writes the result in a file.
- parse output of a.exe in fortran.

This works theoretically but it's not fast enough because i need to call a.exe a lot. Therefore my program spends too much time doing IO.

So, if anyone has an idea to improve my solution, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Do you have the source code that compiles down to `a.exe`? If so, you'd need to refactor it as a subroutine. Other options, if separate runs are independent of one another is to run multiple callers of `a.exe` under **GNU Parallel** or similar.

Comment: I don‘t have the source code. The runs of a.exe are also not independant of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `a.exe` remains a separate executable that operates in the way you describe, there is little improvement possible. After the first invocation, the contents of `a.exe` should be cached in your memory, and further invocations should not be reading `a.exe` from the disk any more till it gets squeezed out.

The time spent on IO of reading and writing the files you are processing is inevitable as long as you are using a disk for interprocess communication; this can be sped up considerably by setting up a ram disk (tmpfs).

Obviously, more could be done if you can rewrite the code of `a.exe`. If you can make it in to an object file that can be linked with your fortran code, that would be ideal. If not, you could make it into a persistent server, for example, so you only run it once. Though if your process is still slow after moving your data files to a ramdisk, you might have other problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. A ram disk sounds promising. It would propably speed up the process by a lot because the disk is not necessarily in the same building. I‘m gonna look into that.